# punto decimal se pierde en el getter y setter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Tengo un problema con unos getter y setter, estos son las propiedades

```
public double PrecioUnitario
{
    get { return _PrecioUnitario; }
    set { _PrecioUnitario = value; }
}

private double _SubTotal;

public double SubTotal
{
    get { return _SubTotal; }
    set { _SubTotal = value; }
}
```

A estas propiedades les asigno valores con punto decimal recuperados de unos textbox

```
    EntProyectoGto.PrecioUnitario = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrecioUnitario.Text);
    EntProyectoGto.SubTotal = Convert.ToDouble(txtSubtotal.Text);
```

pero me doy cuenta con un break point en mi proyecto que cuando se le pasa el valor a la propiedad ya no recibe el punto decimal, en la imagen la primer flecha muestra el valor que recibe la propiedad(1140) y en la flecha de abajo muestro el valor recibido del textbox(11.40)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Buenas Ivxn,

El problema que tienes aquí es que, dependiendo de la región en que estés ejecutando el programa, te va a detectar el separador de decimales como un '`.`' o una '`,`', en tu caso te lo detectará como una coma y al hacer el `Convert.ToDouble` te quita el punto ya que no lo reconoce.

Puedes solucionar esto poniendo lo siguiente:

```
EntProyectoGto.SubTotal = Convert.ToDouble(txtSubtotal.Text.Replace('.',','));
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es debido a la configuración regional que tiene configurado el servidor dónde se está ejecutando la aplicación web.

[image: Configuración Regional]

*Por ejemplo, en mi caso el símbolo decimal es el punto (.) y la separación de miles es la coma (,).*

---

Debes comprender que para convertir una `cadena` a un `doble` se hace uso de la configuración regional.

Por ejemplo:

```
Console.WriteLine("Separador miles: " + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator); // Separador miles: ,
Console.WriteLine("Separador decimal: " + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator); // Separador decimal: .

Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("11.40")); // 11.4
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("114,0")); // 1140
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("11,40")); // 1140       
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("1,140")); // 1140       
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("114,0.40")); // 1140.4      
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("11,40.40")); // 1140.4      
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("1,140.40")); // 1140.4

Console.WriteLine(1140.ToString("C")); // $1,140.00
Console.WriteLine(11.40.ToString("C")); // $11.40

Console.WriteLine();
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false ).NumberFormat;

//      
Console.WriteLine(123456789.ToString("C", nfi )); // $123,456,789.00        

// Configurando para que el formato considere:
nfi.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",";
nfi.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ".";

Console.WriteLine(123456789.ToString("C", nfi )); // $123.456.789,00
```

Obtendrás:

> ```
> Separador miles: ,
> Separador decimal: .
> 11.4
> 1140
> 1140
> 1140
> 1140.4
> 1140.4
> 1140.4
> $1,140.00
> $11.40
>
> $123,456,789.00
> $123.456.789,00
> ```

*PD. el método `Convert.ToDouble` encapsula al método `double.Parse`.*

---

Si tuvieras problemas de no poder alterar la configuración regional, en ese caso deberías usar una cultura diferente, donde utilice la coma (,) como símbolo decimal y el punto (.) como símbolo de miles.

Por ejemplo:

```
CultureInfo elGR = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("el-GR");
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("11,40", elGR)); // 11.40
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("11.40", elGR)); // 1140
```

Obtendrás:

> ```
> 11.4
> 1140
> ```

[**DEMO**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k9ycRz)

---

**Referencia:**

- [Método Double.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.double.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)